# RemoveBackEntry in Prism Universal apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am building a Universal App using Prism framework. In my Windows Phone app, I have a scenario that I navigate from Page 1 to Page 2, and from Page 2 to Page 3. On click of the Back button on Page 3, I want to go back to Page 1.

I figured that only way I can do is by removing the previous entry from the back stack. But, unfortunately, the NavigationService provided by Prism doesn't have such a method. There is ClearHistroy, but that is not what I want.

Is there a way?

Appreciate your help.

Naweed

Answer (score 0):

For the moment the current implementation of PRISM has stopped ( there is a team working on a newer version - so let's hope they extend this for Win10 ).

So you need to do this the 'old' way, get hold of the Frame in the app and remove an entry from the BackStack. You could use a PRISM event to notify the page and in the code behind of that page run

```
if(this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);
}
```